# Regex split words by spaces and all punctuation marks except

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

I am trying to split a file into words by separated by any type and any amount of whitespace and punctuation marks except for the following punctuations ' - ’. How would I do this? This is currently what i have but it isn't separating on periods.

```
$words = preg_split("/((?![a-zA-Z'-’])\s)+/",$file);
```

Comment: So that your question (and your accepted answer) makes sense (and it is most educational) to future SO readers, please improve your question to include a sample input (which includes the extra symbols) and your expected output.  Please set up your input string in such a way that it clarifies the intent of your code.

Comment: for instance, what is your expected output from: `$string="Thi's is a test-string to 'extract' word’s from --  OPs' know what they want.";`

Comment: I have downvoted this question because it is incomplete.  If you improve this question to make it clear and complete, I will be happy to remove my downvote and potentially upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `preg_match_all` is more simple:

```
preg_match_all("~[A-Z'’-]+~ui", $str, $m);
$words = $m[0];
```

I added the u modifier because `’` is outside of the ascii range.
If you need other characters than ascii letters, quotes or hyphens, add them in the character class.